# Hibernate Mapping Generic DAO

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I cannot figure out how to properly map these using the hibernate cfg file.

The entity:

```
public class Employee {

private DetailsOfEmployee details;

public Employee(DetailsOfEmployee details) {
    this.details = details;
}

public DetailsOfEmployee getDetails() {
    return details;
}

public void setDetails(DetailsOfEmployee details) {
    this.details = details;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Employee Details=" + details ;
}

}
```

The Details of the Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="GENERIC")
public class DetailsOfEmployee {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@Column(name= "EMPLOYEE_ID")
private int eID;

@Column(name="EMP_NAME", length=20)
private String empName;

@Column(name= "EMPLOYEE_AGE")
private int empAge;

public DetailsOfEmployee(){
    eID= 0;
    empName="temp";
    empAge=0;
}

public DetailsOfEmployee(int eID, String empName, int empAge) {
    super();
    this.eID = eID;
    this.empName = empName;
    this.empAge = empAge;
}

public int geteID() {
    return eID;
}

public void seteID(int eID) {
    this.eID = eID;
}

public String getEmpName() {
    return empName;
}

public void setEmpName(String empName) {
    this.empName = empName;
}

public int getEmpAge() {
    return empAge;
}

public void setEmpAge(int empAge) {
    this.empAge = empAge;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Employee ID=" + eID + ", Employee Name=" + empName + ", Employee Age="
            + empAge;
}
}
```

Simple DAO:

```
public interface ObjectDAO <T>{


boolean insert(T t);

}
```

Implement Simple DAO:

```
public class ImplObjectDAO<T> implements ObjectDAO<T>{


Session session;
public Set<T> objectSet = new HashSet<>();

public ImplObjectDAO(T t) {

    session= SessionSingleton.getInstance();
}

@Override
public boolean insert(T t){

    if(t != null){

        try{

        session.beginTransaction();

        session.save(t);

        session.getTransaction().commit();

        }
        catch(HibernateException he){

            he.printStackTrace();
            return false;

        }
    }   
    return true;
}
```

Test Class:

```
public class TestObjectDAO {

public static void main(String[] args) {



    DetailsOfEmployee emp1DT = new DetailsOfEmployee(1, "Billy", 25);
    Employee emp1 = new Employee(emp1DT);

    ObjectDAO<Employee> empOpers = new ImplObjectDAO<>(emp1);

    empOpers.insert(emp1);

}

}
```

I have both files mapped properly under the hibernate cfg file.  If I run it as-is, it tells me that the `Employee` class cannot be found.  However, I'm not really sure what to do with the `Employee` class in order for it to get mapped properly since the `Employee` class uses the `DetailsOfEmployee` class to map it's details.

Comment: A class is not an entity if it's not annotated with `@Entity`. What's the purpose of the `Employee` class? Why don't you just use `DetailsOfEmployee`?

Comment: I have annotated the`DetailsOfEmployee` class with the `@Entity`.  I don't actually want the `Employee` class mapped, just the `DetailsOfEmployee` class. When I run this, it tells me that `Employee` is an unknown entity.

Comment: @JBNizet I'm going to post the rest of it to see if i'm implementing it wrong or i'm missing something.  I'm new to hibernate and DAO's.

Comment: If Employee is not a mapped entity, it doesn't make sense to try inserting an Employee in the database. Where would Hibernate store it?